# While-Loop Logic JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

I am trying to understand the logic of the statement block in the while loop. I understand the expression of the while loop, which is as long "idx" is not equal to -1. Push idx value into indices array.

The statement that I have trouble understanding is " idx = array.indexOf(element, idx + 1); "

Is idx increasing after every iteration since it is being increased by 1?

I would appreciate it if someone would help me understand the logic. 
I am quite confused because idx is assign to array.indexOf(element);

The following code snippet is from [Mozilla Developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```js
var indices = [];
var array = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'd'];
var element = 'a';
var idx = array.indexOf(element);

while (idx != -1) {
  indices.push(idx);
  idx = array.indexOf(element, idx + 1);
}

console.log(indices);
// [0, 2, 4]
```

Comment: The indexOf statement makes the array act like a string.  Look up how indexOf works.  You'll find that it stays positive so long as there is an 'a' left to find. Look at: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Comment: You could even be fancy and do `while (~idx) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dvenkatsagar's answer is close.

The point of this

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'd'];
var idx = array.indexOf(element);
```

is to intialize the variable idx's to `0`. Because the index of the array for 'a' is 0

Then the loop begins

```
while (idx != -1) { // This first tests to make sure there is at least one position for a
  indices.push(idx); // pushes that first index position 0 into the array
  idx = array.indexOf(element, idx + 1); //starts the search again at indexOf position 1... because it was just at 0 and found the 'a' element
}
```

So basically,
If this were the array. 
`var array = ['1', 'a', 'a', 'a', '1', 'm'];`

`var idx = array.indexOf(element)`, would return '1' FIRST!

so idx != -1 and the pushing starts!

**Edit: clarify the exit of the while loop.**

As soon as the while loop hits the 4th position of this new array `indexOf(element, 4);` it would then return -1 exiting the while loop.

Comment: Thanks Chris! Your explanation helped me out. I have a second question. The while loop seems to execute the statement when the expression evaluates to false. Is this correct? When the while loop reaches 'b' it evaluates to -1. I would think at this point that the while loop would break but it doesn't. It continues to iterate through the array. I'm a bit confused. I thought while loop only run if the expression evaluates to true.

Comment: @Recon That is not correct actually. indexOf() will continue searching the whole string until it finds an 'a'. You are not looping through the string with while in this example, you are looping while idx != 0. indexOf does the looping for you. Also -1 != false. false == 0. true == 1

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you for time and help. =)